# Django App Issue with ColumnName changed to lower case in the postgres DB

Tags: django, postgresql

I have a working Django app with Postgres DB in the backend. However the coulmn names are updated and switched to lowercase name in backend database, for eg:

Earlier columnName was AccountName, now  changed to accountname  all lowercase. This cases the app to break since the model refers to the oldName.

I tried changing to the Model to the lowercase name but it breaks at different places like DataFrame name and have to make lot of changes to make it work.

```
class AccountStatus(models.Model):
    AccountNumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    AccountName = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

is there any simple solution to this issue, maybe using some alias or any parameter to pass etc?

Thanks for the help.

Tried this :

```
class AccountStatus(models.Model):
    accountnumber = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    accountname = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
```

This results in cascade of changes in Filters, DataFrame key names etc  and many other places.

I am trying to figure out an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a [**`db_column=…`** parameter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#db-column) to specify the name of the column at the database side:

```
class AccountStatus(models.Model):
    AccountNumber = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, db_column='accountnumber', null=True
    )
    AccountName = models.CharField(
        max_length=255, db_column='accountname', null=True
    )
```

Comment: Do I need to run the Migrations after this change? @willem-van-onsem

Comment: @RenukaMulay: if your model is managed yes, for unmanaged models, migrations make no sense.